# Match string value to dataframe value and add to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a string of column names and their datatype called `cols` below:

```
_LOAD_DATETIME datetime,
_LOAD_FILENAME string,
_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER int,
_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP datetime,
ID int
```

Next I make a df from a gsheet I'm reading from the below:

```
import pandas as pd

output = [['table_name', 'schema_name', 'column_name', 'data_type', 'null?', 'default', 'kind', 'expression', 'comment', 'database_name', 'autoincrement', 'DateTime Comment Added'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_DATETIME', '{"type":"TIMESTAMP_LTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'V'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_FILENAME', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'VE'], ['B_ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'V'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP', '{"type":"TIMESTAMP_NTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'TEST', 'VE', '', '2022-02-16'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', 'ID', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":false,"fixed":false}', 'NOT_NULL', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'ID of Account', 'V', '', '2022-02-16'],]
df = pd.DataFrame(output)

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

last_2_days = '2022-02-15'

query_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['comment'] is not None and row['comment'] != '' and (row['DateTime Comment Added'] >= last_2_days):
    comment_data = row['column_name'], row['comment']
    query_list.append(comment_data)
```

when I print out query_list it looks like this, which is getting the correct data since I only want to get the `column_name` and `comment` when the `DateTime Comment Added` column is within the last 2 days of today:

```
[('_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP', 'TEST'), ('ID', 'ID of Account')]
```

What I want to do next (and I'm having trouble figuring out how) is from my `cols` string earlier I want to add the comment  from the query_list to the correct column name in `cols` AND add the word COMMENT before the actual comment

so cols next should look like this:

```
_LOAD_DATETIME datetime,
_LOAD_FILENAME string,
_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER int,
_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP datetime COMMENT 'TEST',
ID int COMMENT 'ID of Account'
```

Comment: I think the simple way is to convert the cols string into a list by breaking it at commas, then you can update values of the list elements as needed. once done, you can convert the list back to the string.

Comment: @Shiping - my cols has the column name and the datatype though, and my query_list is just the column name

Comment: I think you should be able to identify the list element with the column name because the column name is unique.